# PHP GuzzleHttp get response Location header

Tags: php, curl, guzzle6, guzzle

I make a `GET` request with GuzzleHttp 6:

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client as GuzzleClient;
$client = new GuzzleClient([
  'headers' => [
    'Authorization'=>'Bearer XXXX'
  ],        
]);
$downloadUrl = "XXX";
$response = $client->request('GET', $downloadUrl);

$headers = $response->getHeaders();
var_dump($headers['Location']);
var_dump($response->getHeader('Location'));
```

These var_dump prints empty empty arrays like the `Location` header does not exist.

On the response when I make the request with curl from terminal I receive :

```
< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
< Cache-Control: private
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Content-Type: text/plain
< Location: https://xxxx.xxx/yyy/zzz
< request-id: 57388d31-2acf-47b7-80e0-d5a30bcf7f5c
< client-request-id: XXXXX
< x-ms-ags-diagnostic: {"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"North Europe","Slice":"SliceC","Ring":"3","ScaleUnit":"003","RoleInstance":"AGSFE_IN_9","ADSiteName":"NEU"}}
< Duration: 175.4042
< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
< Date: Thu, 29 Aug 2019 09:28:14 GMT
< 
* Connection #0 to host graph.microsoft.com left intact
```

What should I do to get the `Location` header?

***UPDATE***:

By disabling Guzzle redirects there is still the same problem:

```
$response = $client->request('GET', $downloadUrl, ['allow_redirects' => false]);
```

By setting `track_redirects` and `on_redirect` callback nothing happens:

```
$onRedirect = function(RequestInterface $request, ResponseInterface $response, UriInterface $uri){
    echo 'Redirecting! ' . $request->getUri() . ' to ' . $uri . "\n";
};

$response = $client->request('GET', $downloadUrl, [
    'allow_redirects' => [
        'max'             => 10,        // allow at most 10 redirects.
        'strict'          => true,      // use "strict" RFC compliant redirects.
        'referer'         => true,      // add a Referer header
        'protocols'       => ['http', 'https'], // only allow https URLs
        'on_redirect'     => $onRedirect,
        'track_redirects' => true
    ]
]);

var_dump($response->getHeaderLine('X-Guzzle-Redirect-Status-History'));
var_dump($response->getHeaderLine('X-Guzzle-Redirect-History'));
var_dump($response->getHeaderLine('Location'));
```

Prints out:

```
string(0) ""
string(0) ""
string(0) ""
```

Comment: _“like the Location header does not exist”_ - that’s because it doesn’t. Guzzle automatically follows redirects by default - and the headers you are looking at are those of the follow-up request that causes, not of the original one. https://guzzle3.readthedocs.io/http-client/http-redirects.html

Comment: I use GuzzleHttp 6, I tried to disable redirects, or to execute a callback when an redirect occurs  and the callback wasn't executed

Comment: Then try and set `track_redirects`, and check the content of the headers `X-Guzzle-Redirect-History` and `X-Guzzle-Redirect-Status-History` afterwards.

Comment: @misorude I updated the question... still nothing

Comment: Have you checked what the actual response is? Maybe your request via Guzzle gets a _different_ response from what you see when you make the request using cURL (due to some significant request characteristics being different somehow) - so it could just be that you are looking for redirects that aren’t happening in the first place …?

Comment: @misorude it looks is the same in all other headers that I receive. I will make a `var_dump` inside Guzzle library soon after the response is received to make sure this too.

Comment: the ['allow_redirects' => false] has fixed my issue. Thanks mate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change Guzzle handler to Curl.

***First you should make sure that `php-curl` is installed in your system.***

If you didn't had the `php-curl` installed, after the installatin check if you still didn't receive the `Location` header.

***If the problem persist you can try***:

```
use GuzzleHttp\HandlerStack;
use GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlHandler;

$handler = new CurlHandler();
$stack = HandlerStack::create($handler); // Wrap w/ middleware

$client = new GuzzleClient([
    'headers' => $headers,
    'handler'=> $stack
]);
```